# Can we find $ a + b $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

How can we find the value of $ a + b $ in the following question? a & b are integers.

> **Question:** If $ a^{2} \times b^{3} = 216 $, find $ a + b $.

Comment: what about the $a,b$ integer or not?

Comment: Hint: $216 = 2^33^3$.

Comment: @ Essam, No other information is provided.

Comment: It might be provided in the context of the chapter you are studying, the class, etc. Without context, the question has no meaning - or rather, too many possible meanings. @Zubair

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Agree with you :) Can we solve using exponent rules.

Comment: Agree that it is not well defined, but then ask if we can solve it? You haven't asked a question yet. @Zubair

Comment: Allowing non integer solutions leads to an uninteresting problem, this is unlikely.

Comment: $a^2$ or $a^3$ ???

Comment: Is a,b an integer?

Comment: @user236182 fair enough.  I had not looked hard enough for multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is asking for non integer solutions:

$$b=(216/a^2)^{1/3}$$

Now add that to $a$.

If the question is asking for integer solutions we observe that:

$$\frac{216}{a^2}=b^3$$

Meaning that $a^2$ needs to be a factor of $216$, a perfect square, and when division is operated it must make a perfect cube.

We check the factors of $216$:

$$1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,18,24,27,36,54,72,108,216$$

The only perfect squares are :

$$1,4,9,36$$

$$\frac{216}{1}=216=6^3$$

$$\frac{216}{4}=54$$

$$\frac{216}{9}=24$$

$$\frac{216}{36}=6$$

Thus the only thing that works from the above is:

$$a=1,b=6$$

$$a+b=7$$

But if you allow negative integer solutions:

$a=-1,b=6$ also works

$$a+b=5$$